# How to create a map column to count occurrences without udaf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark3

I would like to create a `Map` column which counts the number of occurrences.

For instance:

```
+---+----+
|  b|   a|
+---+----+
|  1|   b|
|  2|null|
|  1|   a|
|  1|   a|
+---+----+
```

would result in

```
+---+--------------------+
|  b|                 res|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[a -> 2.0, b -> 1.0]|
|  2|                  []|
+---+--------------------+
```

For the moment, in Spark 2.4.6, I was able to make it using udaf.

While bumping to Spark3 I was wondering if I could get rid of this udaf (I tried using the new method `aggregate` without success)

Is there an efficient way to do it?
(For the efficiency part, I am able to test easily)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a Spark 3 solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy($"b",$"a").count()
  .groupBy($"b")
  .agg(
    map_from_entries(
      collect_list(
        when($"a".isNotNull,struct($"a",$"count"))
      )
    ).as("res")
  )
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+----------------+
|  b|             res|
+---+----------------+
|  1|[b -> 1, a -> 2]|
|  2|              []|
+---+----------------+
```

Here the solution using `Aggregator`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

val countOcc = new Aggregator[String, Map[String,Int], Map[String,Int]] with Serializable {
    def zero: Map[String,Int] = Map.empty.withDefaultValue(0)
    def reduce(b: Map[String,Int], a: String) = if(a!=null) b + (a -> (b(a) + 1)) else b
    def merge(b1: Map[String,Int], b2: Map[String,Int]) = {
      val keys = b1.keys.toSet.union(b2.keys.toSet)
      keys.map{ k => (k -> (b1(k) + b2(k))) }.toMap
    }
    def finish(b: Map[String,Int]) = b
    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Map[String,Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String,Int]])
    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String, Int]])
}

val countOccUDAF = udaf(countOcc)

df
  .groupBy($"b")
  .agg(countOccUDAF($"a").as("res"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+----------------+
|  b|             res|
+---+----------------+
|  1|[b -> 1, a -> 2]|
|  2|              []|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Added the solution with Aggregator

Comment: thank you very much. I am going to accept this one. Do you know the impact on performances of using `udaf` instead of `TypedColumn`? (I will probably try it soon and come back with the results here)

Comment: Also, may I suggest to replace this: `b1(k) + b2(k)` by this: `b1.getOrElse(k, 0) + b2.getOrElse(k, 0)` ? (Except that I was struggling to apply this on a dataframe (the `val countOccUDAF = udaf(countOcc)` saved me), I came up with the exact same solution !)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken `b1.getOrElse(k, 0)` is not necessary because I used `Map.empty.withDefaultValue(0)`

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `collect_list` with UDF, but only if you groupings are not too lage:

```
val udf_histo = udf((x:Seq[String]) => x.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size))

df.groupBy($"b")
  .agg(
    collect_list($"a").as("as")
  )
  .select($"b",udf_histo($"as").as("res"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+----------------+
|  b|             res|
+---+----------------+
|  1|[b -> 1, a -> 2]|
|  2|              []|
+---+----------------+
```

This should be faster than UDAF: [Spark custom aggregation : collect_list+UDF vs UDAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294294/spark-custom-aggregation-collect-listudf-vs-udaf)

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the reading. Do you mind if I take time to test before accepting one of the answers ?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Added the solution with Aggregator

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this is spark 2.4

```
//GET THE COUNTS
val groupedCountDf = originalDf.groupBy("b","a").count

//CREATE MAPS FOR EVERY COUNT | EMPTY MAP FOR NULL KEY
//AGGREGATE THEM AS ARRAY 

val dfWithArrayOfMaps =  groupedCountDf
.withColumn("newMap",  when($"a".isNotNull, map($"a",$"count")).otherwise(map()))
.groupBy("b").agg(collect_list($"newMap") as "multimap")

//EXPRESSION TO CONVERT ARRAY[MAP] -> MAP

val mapConcatExpr = expr("aggregate(multimap, map(), (k, v) -> map_concat(k, v))")

val finalDf = dfWithArrayOfMaps.select($"b", mapConcatExpr.as("merged_data"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with a single `groupBy` and a slightly complex sql expression. This solution works for Spark 2.4+

```scala
df.groupBy("b")
  .agg(expr("sort_array(collect_set(a)) as set"),
       expr("sort_array(collect_list(a)) as list"))
  .withColumn("res",
       expr("map_from_arrays(set,transform(set, x -> size(filter(list, y -> y=x))))"))
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+---------+----------------+
|  b|   set|     list|             res|
+---+------+---------+----------------+
|  1|[a, b]|[a, a, b]|[a -> 2, b -> 1]|
|  2|    []|       []|              []|
+---+------+---------+----------------+
```

The idea is to collect the data from column `a` twice: one time into a set and one time into a list. Then with the help of [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) for each element of the set the number of occurences of the particular element in the list is counted. Finally, the set and the number of elements are combined with [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays).

However I cannot say if this approach is really faster than a UDAF.

Comment: this does not scale very good if groupings are large. All data for 1 group is pulled into 1 executor

Comment: @RaphaelRoth that's true. I would guess that it depends on the actual data if it's faster to collect everything to one executor or if it's better to do the second group by

Comment: Also, I might be wrong but if there's any performance impact on `sort_array` and `filter`?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken yes, depending on your data the `sort_array` and `filter` might or might not be faster than a uadf